# Update a whole table with PHP every x minutes according to a CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, transactions, cron

I have to update a big table (products) in a MySQL database, every 10 minutes with PHP. I have to run the PHP script with cron job, and I get the most up to date products from a CSV file. The table has currently ~18000 rows, and unfortunately I can not tell how much it will change in a 10 min period. The most important thing is of course I do not want the users to notice the update in the background.

These are my ideas and fears:

- Idea1: I know that there is a way to [load a csv file into a table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) with MySQL, so maybe I can use a transaction to truncate the table, and import the CSV. But even if I use transactions, as long as the table is large, I'm afraid that there will be a little chance for some users to see the empty database.
- Idea2: I could compare the old and the new csv file [with a library](https://github.com/goodby/csv) and only update/add/remove the changed rows. This way I think there it's not possible for a user to see an empty database, but I'm afraid this method will cost a lot of RAM and CPU, and I'm on a shared hosting.

So basically I would like to know which method is the most secure to update a table completely without the users noticing it.

Comment: You will have to be careful about CPU and RAM either way, since you are on shared hosting. How many rows, approximately, are you talking about in total? And how many are likely to change in ten minutes? Occasional RAM spikes are generally forgivable, but CPU is the tricky one: you may find `usleep()` is helpful here to allow other apps on the box to get a look-in. (And, as I have recently discovered, CSV import can be done in a very small RAM footprint anyway).

Comment: Thanks halfer, I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: 18K rows isn't that bad for <10 mins of write time. Do some tests on a real shared host, using transactions. Wipe the table and re-insert if you think most/all will change, and update only changed rows if you think only a few will.

Comment: I do something very similar to this.  I download CDR records in .csv format and use a PHP script to update a MySQL table every hour with new data.  PHP script runs with cron, works great.  Your situation is a bit different because you are updating, not adding.  Is there any reason to not do an update to your original table every 10 mins?  Does your CSV data have a field that can be used as a primary key?  You can comb through the CSV for that primary key and set up a condition that will update the information in your table if the primary key already exists or insert if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming InnoDB and default isolation level, you can start a transaction, delete all rows, insert your new rows, then commit. Before the commit completes, users will see the previous state.

While the transaction is open (after the deletes), updates will block, but SELECTs will not. Since it's a read only table for the user, it won't be an issue. They'll still be able to `SELECT` while the transaction is open.

You can learn the details by reading about [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). The gist of it is that any time someone performs a `SELECT`, MySQL uses the data in the database plus the rollback segment to fetch the previous state until the transaction is committed or rolled back.

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html):

> InnoDB uses the information in the rollback segment to perform the
>   undo operations needed in a transaction rollback. It also uses the
>   information to build earlier versions of a row for a consistent read.

Only after the commit completes will the users see the new data instead of the old data, and they won't see the new data until their current transaction is over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, it's a read only table. Let's say I have a database with millions of rows (which is not the actual situation, I'm just curious). Even with transaction, commit would take some time in this case, isn't it? Can you tell me what actually happens during the commit, and if someone tries to select from the table in this case?

Comment: I updated my answer because the response was too long for a comment.